# Will Alaska always give credit for flights if both marketing and actual airline are partners?

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs, alaska-airlines

As an example, KLM flight 6162 is not on their [list of KLM flights that they credit for mileage](http://www.alaskaair.com/content/mileage-plan/partners/klm.aspx). But the funky thing is that both KLM (the marketing airline) and the actual airline (Delta) are both codeshare partners. So do they give you credit for this somehow, anyway, even though it's not in the range they specify on that web page (0001-2499)? If they do give you credit, does the mileage count towards elite status?

### Clarifications

- I realize that the web page already says they won't give credit, what I'm wondering is if someone out there has personally gotten credit for one of these flights anyway
- I realize I could call Alaska and ask but I hate calling people on the phone, and...
- Based on reading other forums, it sounds like the answer to this question kind of varies based on the whim of the person you're talking to at the airline; that's why I'm wondering if *anyone has actually done this successfully*

Comment: This is a bit specialized. Can you ask a more general question? And practically speaking, have you called the airline?

Comment: Ok, generalized it a bit. Haven't called the airline 'cuz a) it's too late at night and b) if I wanted to talk to a person, I wouldn't posting here :-)

Comment: I don't think specialised is a bad thing at all. If at all, we *want* more specific questions.

Comment: The question is in fact answered on the page you link to. Why do you think the web page is wrong?

Comment: @DJClayworth Ok I clarified the question again. I do think the web page is likely stating the rules accurately enough, but I'm wondering how often they are actually bent (ideally I'd like to hear from a real customer who's actually done this).

Comment: This question illustrates the differences between operated by and marketed by. It can be very fuzzy what will and won't get credit when the marketing carrier and operating carrier are different. Thanks for the followup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up calling Alaska Airlines about something else so also asked about this question. Turns out it doesn't matter what the flight is marketed as, what matters is which airline is actually operating the flight. So they would give credits for all the flights listed in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It says pretty clear that the flight isn't eligible:

> To qualify for mileage accrual, flights must be marketed by KLM and
>   must **also** fall within the eligible flight number range.

Delta sells tickets on that very flight under its own flight code, for that you would be credited.

Comment: Already realized that. Added clarification to my question to (hopefully) make it clear what I'm actually asking.